# Priority API: Getting image link instead of base64 content

Tags: php, odata, priority-web-sdk

When I fetch recent/new items with (full data row), the field: EXTFILENAME can cause system halt.
In order to fix that, I have to use the "fields" filter! My query will stop being dynamic, Any new field have to be updated in my query.
The same problem as in any SQL query, Its simple to SELECT * rather than SELECT field1,field2,field3 Just because I dont want this EXTFILENAME field.

Why Priority stopped sending a link to media files in LOGPART ?!
If I want to grab 10 items, it will kill the network if all rows have images!

Can you please give us the power to decide how we get the image ? Base64 or Link ?

/LOGPART?$filter=UDATE gt (time)&$fields=PARTNAME,........,PART
/LOGPART?$filter=UDATE gt (time)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this sounds like a feature request or complaint for some product you're using. Stack overflow is not the place for this.

Comment: 1. @Evert , The Priority CRM community encourage us to use StackOVerflow and add their TAG "priority-web-sdk" .
2. Not all of us are English native speakers, We can write/read but we cant do it perfect, I may wrote it in a way you understand it as an AD but its not.
3. I really want a help from somebody to guide me how can I fetch a ROW DATA from this crm without getting the Image BASE64 encoded, but get the link.

I read thousands of posts here with the same issue in different aspects. Again English is my 3rd language, Dont judge me if not everything was clear enogh.

Comment: Hi Massalha, to me this sounds like some pretty bad business practices and offloading their customer support to others. Not your fault, and didn't mean to be rude specifically to you; Stack overflow has pretty specific and thoughtful rules and the Priority company should provide actual support. You're being shafted here.

Answer (score 0):

In version 21.0 files are returned as a data URI. It is documented here: https://prioritysoftware.github.io/restapi/request/#requesting-attachments.